# Trying to calculate running time of an algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, runtime, big-o, time-complexity

I have the following algorithm:

```
for(int i = n; i > 0; i--){
    for(int j = 1; j < n; j *= 2){
        for(int k = 0; k < j; k++){
            ... // constant number C of operations
        }
    }
}
```

I need to calculate the algorithm's running time complexity,

I'm pretty sure the outer loop runs `O(n)` times, the middle loop runs `O(log(n))` times, and the inner loop runs `O(log(n))` times as well, but I'm not so sure about it.

The final result of the running time complexity is `O(n^2)`, but I have no idea how.

Hope someone could give me a short explanation about it, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each `i`, the second loop runs `j` through the powers of 2 until it exceeds `n`: 1, 2, 4, 8, ... , 2<sup>h</sup>, where h=int(log<sub>2</sub>n). So the body of the inner-most loop runs 2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + ... + 2<sup>h</sup> =  2<sup>h+1</sup>-1 times. And 2<sup>h+1</sup>-1 = 2<sup>int(log<sub>2</sub>n)+1</sup>-1 which is O(n).

Now, the outer loop executes `n` times. This gives complexity of the whole thing O(n*n).